# SSL Handshake exception for HTTP Get method - ASP.NET core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to invoke rest method with asp.net core 2.1 but keep getting the ssl exception even I'm using a http in this call. The code that im using is:

```
public async Task<bool> SyncTickets()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var path = "http://testdesk.vmw.be:8082/helpdesk/WebObjects/Helpdesk.woa/ra/PriorityTypes?username=admin&apiKey=bJZw2jP8wgtyGXI736K6DfUiEjJYTLuqC8fGuOBN";
            Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseMsg = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Object>();
                return true;
            }
            return false; 

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
```

Exception is:

> {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format

Exception occur on `GetAsync` method.
When I'm using the same path to test trough postman or browser it's working perfectly fine, I'm getting the response.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your server requires encryption anyway and redirects to https?

If that's the case and https still reports add before creating `HttpClient`:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

This will accept all certs. **This setting is global to your app. DO NOT USE IT IN PRODUCTION.** If your server uses selfsigned cert or internal CA issued cert use it only for testing. **In production add proper validation of internal CA or accept only specific self-signed cert**. Browsers might have internal certs or CAs added on PC's from domain controller or via group policy and therefore they don't report them untrusted.

Also, for https you can explicitly use TLS protocols. Add the following line before creating `HttpClient` and try again:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

If you have defined protocol set at your server, you can narrow down protocol list just to enable those actually supported.